# extract data fr .sql file to csv

Tags: sql, extract

i have .sql file sent by a vendor for which i am trying to extract data from as my co is in the midst of account closure with vendor.

i believe i need to create a connection to the vendor database with my login and run the sql file but i have no idea how to do the settings.

correct me if i am on the right track.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

i tried to open the sql file with notepad, excel, and DBeaver but it is not working.

i have no idea how to convert the sql file into csv data. When i open the file with all above methods, i see what seems like some sql queries amidst unreadable symbols instead of any real data that i can transform into a readable table.

Comment: First, tag the database you are using.  SQL files contain scripts to create tables and\or insert data into it. It might even have create database statement in it as well. How they are loaded may show slight differences depending on the database they are used with. Some are just open and run with the database's tool, some are run through restore command line tools. Once you have it in the database, getting CSV could be done in many ways, from database tools itself to some external coding say with C#, Go etc.

Comment: Contact your vendor.

Comment: @jarlh the vendor was not helpful. I asked for csv extract and they gave this sql file. I asked how to create the connection to execute the sql file. Told me to speak to my own tech team or developer.

Comment: Perhaps it's a non-windows file format. Ask a Linux guy to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually an SQL File is a Query, that can be executed on a Database to read or write data.
You should be able to read it with "editor" in Windows.

If the content is not readable for the editor, it is likely that the file is corrupted.

If the file is readable and contains the keyword "SELECT", it should be possible to execute it on the Database with a database client application.
You'll need to use a client application that is compatible with the kind of Database (e.g. Oracle, MySQL, DB2, Postgres) your vendor has.

The easiest solution would be to ask the vendor to run the script for you and give you the resulting data in a csv file. Since it is their database they should know how to run an SQL script.